# Prolog - procedure `A-B' does not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm using the SWISH SWI online PROLOG website available here: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/

I'm trying to write a simple program that gets the head and tail of a list via the following query `? - list([H | T])`.

However I get the following error: *procedure `A-B' does not exist*.

This is my list:

```
list([a, 2,2, b, 3,4,5]).
```

Theoretically speaking, should I expect 'a' or 'A' as a head result?
The tail should be [2, 2, b, 3, 4, 5].

Comment: There is a space within `? -`. It should read `?-`. But most probably you do not need to type `?-` at all. Rather enter your query in the query window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Swish like this:

[image]

But as you can see you have a problem. Your predicate doesn't actually *do* anything, aside from verifying that what you passed into it is a `./2` structure (what a non-empty prolog list is).

To get what you want, try something like this — https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/DbwbcXxp.pl

```
pop( [H|T] , H , T ) .
```

Now when you execute the query `pop( [a,b,c,d,e,f], H , T )`, you get

```
H = a
T = [b,c,d,e,f]
```

But you don't actually need a predicate to decompose a list. Assuming you have a non-empty list `L`, you can decompose it into its head and tail using the unification operator (`=/2`): Executing this query,

```
L  = [a,b,c,d,e,f], [H|T] = L .
```

yields

```
H = a
T = [b,c,d,e,f]
```

as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
% cat a.pl
list([a,2,2,b,3,4,5]).

% swipl a.pl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.4.2)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit https://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- list([H|T]).
H = a,
T = [2, 2, b, 3, 4, 5].

?- halt.
%
```

Is this what you want to do?